# Add new column to the existing one PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I have list of the servers, for them I'm used commands Resolve `-DnsName`, this command has different parameters and to receive all the data that I need (NS, MX, CNAME, A) records, I need to make multiple commands.

```
$servers = get-content "C:\Users\Olehsa\Desktop\ttt.txt"


    $a1 = foreach ($server in $servers) {

     [System.Net.Dns]::resolve($server)
    }
```

After every command I have a list with 1-3 columns.

```
#NS
$a2 = foreach ($server in $servers) {

    Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type NS -DnsOnly | select PrimaryServer, NameHost,NameExchange,Strings + $a3 

}

#MX
$a3 = foreach($server in $servers) {

    Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type MX -DnsOnly | select NameExchange
} 

#TXT
$a4 = foreach($server in $servers) {

    Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type TXT | select Strings
}
```

I receive this data:

```
HostName   Aliases AddressList    
--------   ------- -----------    
google.com {}      {172.217.22.46}
```

and this :

```
NameHost       NameExchange
-------------  --------       
              ns1.google.com             
              ns4.google.com             
              ns3.google.com             
              ns2.google.com
```

And the question is, How I can merge the to one big list with multiple columns?

P.s.  Without using the PS-objects, because if I using it, I'm putting all data to 1 cell. 
I have the list with 3 columns, I need to add one more column with

Comment: But there are different columns after different parameters. E. g. NS records have 'NameHost' and MX records haven't 'NameHost' but have 'NameExchange'.
How you gonna merge different columns?

Comment: I just want to add this columns to the whole list, where will be NameHost and NameExchange,

Comment: You are quite ambigous, you should specify what you have, what you get (with what code) and what you expect/want by [editing](https://serverfault.com/posts/932023/edit) your question.

Comment: Already changed the questions, I think it will be more clear for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put this into one `ForEach` and
when getting multiple results for a single field `-Join` them

```
## Q:\Test\2018\09\21\SF_932023.ps1
$servers = get-content "C:\Users\Olehsa\Desktop\ttt.txt"

$result = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server        = $server
        NameHost      = ((Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type NS -DnsOnly).NameHost|Sort) -Join ', '
        NameExchange  = ((Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type MX -DnsOnly).NameExchange|Sort) -Join ', '
        Strings       = ((Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type TXT).Strings) -Join ', '
     }
}

$result|fl
```

Sample output:

```
Server       : google.com
NameHost     : ns1.google.com, ns2.google.com, ns3.google.com, ns4.google.com
NameExchange : alt1.aspmx.l.google.com, alt2.aspmx.l.google.com, alt3.aspmx.l.google.com, alt4.aspmx.l.google.com, aspmx.l.google.com
Strings      : docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e, facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95, v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
This is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Can we specify external DNS server like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 ?